# How to apply a patch in a remote repository?

Tags: eclipse, windows, svn, tortoisesvn, development-environment

**Summary:**

I created a patch in my local machine, but I need to apply this patch in a remote machine.
I'm using [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) in both machines. How can I do this in a proper way ?

---

**Context:**

I have development environment in a project that is not very common, I guess. I could develop it in a remote VM, but the Eclipse and the entire machine are so slow that I think is unproductive. Also, I have to use a VPN to connect to the VM, which makes my connection slower. Because of that, I want to develop in my local machine, but, for the build I need to apply this patch in this remote VM to test if the changes were made correctly. I noticed that a patch can't be applied to a unversioned file, for that, I have to clean my entire remote repository with Tortoise and apply the patch again. But I wonder if this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with two build environments, you have to version ALL of the source files. The only thing that will not be under version control are the `build` directory and the machine-specific configuration files.

So if a file is not under version control somewhere, it is likely because your project setup is not correct. Take the time put everything in a single folder that can be under version control, start tracking it and then have the two machines communicating with the same repository.

Side note : it is quite common to develop on a machine and build on an other, you should be able to get a simple and efficient work environment quite easily.

I hope I got you question right. If not, please provide more specific info like your project's tree, the reason why you cannot test on your development machine, why is this specific file not under version control and anything else relevant.

Comment: John, how can I make sure that all my source files are been versioned, as you suggested ? I'm new to tortoise also.

Comment: I know better with git but the idea is to have a clean project, add the project's root directory to version control, ignore the build folder and machine-specific files then commit to the repository and checkout that exact same repository on the build machine.